# how to set class parameters to be properties in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, class, oop, properties

Hi I'm learning Kotlin and Im struggling to find an easy way to set a class's parameters to be properties.

for example:

```kotlin
class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String){
    // code I'm looking for to make next 2 lines work
}

var bob = Person("Bob", "Smith")

print(bob.firstName)
```

so far only way I've been able to get it to work is by doing the below but I feel like there has to be an easier way I'm just not finding.

```kotlin
class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String){
    var firstName: String? = null
    
    init {
        this.firstName = firstName
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `val` or `var` keywords directly in your class signature.

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

If you define your class as a data class, the compiler will enforce the usage of these keywords:

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```